# iOS apps using CloudKit

Tags: software-development, ios

I am curious which App Store apps are using Apple the recent MBaaS technology called CloudKit. I want to see how stable this technology is at operational apps.

Comment: Interesting question. I always had the same question floating around in my head about Stackmob, Parse, Firebase, etc. If you're wondering about MBaaS adoption in production in general, check out the customer pages from [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/customers/) and [Parse](https://parse.com/customers).

Comment: When looking at the posts at StackOverflow and the apple def forums I get the impression that the interest is much less than it deserves. I'm doing a lot with CloudKit. See https://github.com/evermeer/EVCloudKitDao But I have not heard of anyone using it in production. I am planning to release an app that is using CloudKit in about 2 months.